# Print a line if it matches AND if a condition is met in the N lines before and N lines after

Tags: python-3.x, pattern-matching

what is the most sensible way of doing this? Once I have my match, I want to know what's happening in the 100 lines before, and in the 100 lines after. Here is the example of the loop

```
 with open(pile, "r") as pileup:
            for i, line in enumerate(pileup):
                fields = line.split('\t')
                if fields[0] == v.CHROM and (v.start -1) == fields[1]:
                        print(str(v)) #printing the query string #I hope that then the variable i has the value of the match line number
                        for line in range(i-101, i+101):
                            if fields[2] >= 4:
                                 print (line)     #here I want to pring the line meeting the condition
```

I know using enumerate should allow to have a line number. But my code doesn't seem to work, it runs forever. 
Thanks for any tips

Comment: Why not just cache your most recent 100 lines and then when you need them, you can add on the next 100?  This is failing because your `line` in your second for loop doesn't have the same meaning as your first. Additionally, using `range` in this way won't actually affect how your file is being read.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good time to use a deque.

A deque can be used as a fixed length list. That way you'll never have over a 100 elements in it.

```
from collections import deque

cache = deque(maxlen=100)
full_list = []

with open(pile, "r") as pileup:
    for line in pileup:
        fields = line.split('\t')

        cache.append(fields)
        if fields[0] == v.CHROM and (v.start -1) == fields[1]:
            break

    # once you reach your condition
    # you can grab the next 100 lines as well
    full_list = list(cache)

    for i, line in enumerate(pileup):
        if i < 100:
            full_list.append(line.split('\t'))
        else:
            break
```